# What does "|" mean other that bitwise or

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-beam

I came across the following statement. What does `|` mean other than bitwise or?

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

# argv = None  # if None, uses sys.argv
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(argv)
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
  lines = (
      pipeline
      | beam.Create([
          'To be, or not to be: that is the question: ',
          "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer ",
          'The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, ',
          'Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, ',
      ]))
```

Comment: `p` refers to what? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)

Comment: Read the official documentation: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Objects in Python can implement operators like bitwise-or to have meanings of their own. It looks like you're using a library that's doing so for the `p` object on that line. Without knowing the type of `p`, we can't help you tell what it does.

Comment: `|` means whatever the relevant object (generally the one on the left side) wants it to mean.  This looks like a situation where a programmer got carried away with that ability.

Comment: full code is updated

Comment: @ItayDumay it's not Biwise Or in this context.

Comment: @rafadeboas its added to the story.

Comment: @Blckknght you are  correct.

Answer (score 3):

Python lets any class redefine `|` to mean whatever it wants it to mean.   beam.io uses `|` as a shortcut for the apply operator.  The results are intended to look like a Unix pipeline, which also uses `|`.